# How to use gnuplot xdata time with feedgnuplot?

Tags: perl, gnuplot

I'm using feedgnuplot and gnuplot to show real-time data on my linux desktop. 
My data is produced by command which outputs 12 space separated integer values on each line and up to four lines per second.
I like to add the time, so I put time in front of the line before feeding data to feedgnuplot.
If I specify the time as seconds, the data is properly plotted, but the x-axis is quite unreadable:

```
data-producer | 
while read -a line
do
    echo -n $(date +"%s")
    for n in "${line[@]}"
    do
        echo -en "\t$n"
    done
    echo
done |
feedgnuplot --terminal 'qt' \
            --domain \
            --stream 1 \
            --xlen 5 \
            --with lines \
            --set "xdata time" \
            --set "timefmt '%s'"
```

So I tried to get human readable time on the horizontal scale:

```
data-producer | 
while read -a line
do
    echo -n $(date +"%H:%M:%S")
    for n in "${line[@]}"
    do
        echo -en "\t$n"
    done
    echo
done |
feedgnuplot --terminal 'qt' \
            --domain \
            --stream 1 \
            --xlen 5 \
            --with lines \
            --set "xdata time" \
            --set "timefmt '%H:%M:%S'"
```

This line does not work because feedgnuplot complains about comparison operators not applied to numeric data:

```
Argument "09:45:58" isn't numeric in numeric lt (<) at /usr/bin/feedgnuplot line 694.
Argument "09:45:57" isn't numeric in numeric ge (>=) at /usr/bin/feedgnuplot line 797.
```

Looking into the feedgnuplot code (it is a perl script) I see that comparison is performed on x values to sort them and to assess whether the graph has to be plotted again or not.

Is it possible to have feedgnuplot handle times by using some command line switches? If not, is there any other option before resorting to patching the feedgnuplot source code? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gnuplot requires some special settings for datetime data (e.g. a `using` statement must be specified). Therefore, `feedgnuplot` provides an own option for time data, `--timefmt <format>`:

```
for i in `seq 0 100`; do echo $i; sleep 1; done | 
while read -a line
do
    echo -n $(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    for n in "${line[@]}"
    do
        echo -en "\t$n"
    done
    echo
done |
feedgnuplot --terminal 'qt' \
            --domain \
            --stream 1 \
            --lines \
            --timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" \
            --set 'format x "%H:%M:%S"'
```

Note, that different versions of gnuplot use different reference points for time in seconds, so that versions 4.6 (reference 1st January 2000) and earlier give wrong results when using `%s`. So it is better to use a time format of the kind `%H:%M:%S`. In the code above I used a fully defined datetime to avoid possible problems with day-spanning plots.

Comment: It sounded good, but when I tried it, I got gnuplot complaining about the time number as in:

    gnuplot> 1443531574 877
             ^
             line 0: invalid command

This happens only when parameter '--set "xdate time" ' is used.

Comment: I finally found some time to test the code. See the update for a working script.